# NSManagedObjectContext returns nil in Core Data app (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm trying to save a string into a database every time a button is pressed but when I run the project, I get that on my console: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Info''`.

Referring to the Data Model, I have created a .xcdatamodeld with an Entity named 'Info' and, inside it, an attribute named 'path' with a type of string.

I've created three functions. "enterdata" Checks if the name is avaliable or not by calling "findData". If the name is avaliable, a new data is recorded throught "newData", if not, it looks for a different name.

I've been looking for some similar questions and I've found out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596487/entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter-core-data/11596607#11596607). It says that de ManagedObjectContext has to be passed to the View Controller but I don't understand what does it mean.

Here's my .h code:

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

Here's my .m code:

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@synthesize managedObjectContext;

int  iSavedNum = 1;
bool bCanSave;

//Enter data
- (IBAction) enterdata:(id)sender {

    //Search if data is already registered
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/info%i.png",docDir, iSavedNum];
    [self findData:path :@"path"];

    //If data is already saved, save it with new name.
    if (bCanSave == NO) {
        for (iSavedNum = 1; bCanSave == YES; iSavedNum++) {
            [self findData:path :@"path"];
            if (bCanSave == YES) {
                [self newData:path :@"path"];
            }
        }
    } else {
        [self newData:path :@"path"];
    }

}

//Input new data
- (void) newData:(NSString *)value:(NSString *)key {

    //Create ManagedObjectContext and ManagedObjectModel
    __0AppDelegate *appDelegate = (__0AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObjectModel *newRecord;

    //Put the data to the Entity
    NSString *entityName = @"Info";
    newRecord = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newRecord setValue:value forKey:key];

    //Errors management and cheking
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
    NSLog(@"Info Saved. Value: %@ Key: %@", value, key);

}

//Find Data
- (void) findData:(NSString *)valor:(NSString *)key {

    //Create ManagedObjectContext
    __0AppDelegate *appDelegate = (__0AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    //Call the Entity and make a request
    NSString *entityName = @"Info";
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    //Create predicate to call specific info
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ = %@)", key, valor];
    [request setPredicate:pred];

    //Errors management and creation of an array with found info
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    //Set if the name is avaliable or not
    if ([objects count] == 0) {
        bCanSave = YES;
    } else {
        bCanSave = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you create the managed object context? What does `[self managedObjectContext]` do? The error message indicates that it returns `nil`.

Comment: In my .h I have this `@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;` and it's synthesized in the .m, so it's theoretically declared. Isn't it?

Comment: It is *declared* as a instance variable and property, but the value is `nil`. You have to create a managed object context from a Core Data model and a persistent store. Perhaps you did that in the `AppDelegate` or somewhere else in your code? Then you have to use the managed object context from there.

Comment: Do you mean this: `CoreDataAppDelegate *appDelegate =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

   NSManagedObjectContext *context =
    [appDelegate managedObjectContext];`

Comment: I have just tried it and the problem is the same. NSManagedObjectContext is still returning nil.

Comment: Perhaps you should single-step in the debugger to find out why `[appDelegate managedObjectContext]` returns `nil`.

Comment: Have you seen the answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596487/entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter-core-data/11596607#11596607) ? It says that the MOContext has to be passed to the ViewController. What does it mean?

Comment: Many apps have a single MOC that is created in the application delegate, this seems also to be the case here. How you pass the MOC from application delegate to view controller does not matter at all, that is just a matter of taste. You should check if `[appDelegate managedObjectContext]` returns `nil`, and if it does, single-step through that method call to find the cause.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I finally found my mistake in the `- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It tells you exactly what the error is:

> nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter

That means that on this line:

```
newRecord = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

The variable `context` is `nil`. This means that your `managedObjectContext` method isn't working correctly. You don't show this so there's not much more we can add.

Comment: It seems from above comments that the OP already created a MOC in the application delegate, but did not set the `managedObjectContext` property from that "global" MOC.

Answer (score 0):

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in `appDelegate`

```
/*initiate the managed Object Context */  
CoreDataManager *coreDataManager = [CoreDataManager sharedDataManager];
    coreDataManager.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

where `CoreDataManager` is my core date manager which explicitly contains all the core data save, delete methods

Or

```
yourClassObject.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

so context get initialized