# CoreData: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter

Tags: ios, core-data

I am very new to Core Data and have been trying to following many tutorials, but most of them put all of the Core Data methods into AppDelegate. I have read that it is better to stay away from AppDelegate and use a custom Data Model class to manage these methods.

I have created a custom class to manage all of my data named `MyDataModel`. I implemented the boiler plate Core Data code. In one of my view controllers I have a simple method to implement some data using Core Data:

```
- (void)getProfile {
/*
 * getProfile
 */
    NSLog(@"%@", _Model.managedObjectContext);
    Users *user = (Users *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Users" inManagedObjectContext:_Model.managedObjectContext];

    // Set Data
    [user setValue:@"John" forKey:@"fname"];
    [user setValue:@"Smith" forKey:@"lname"];
    NSError *error;
    [_Model.managedObjectContext save:&error];
}
```

The code from the header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Users.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "DataModel.h"

@interface ProfileViewController : UIViewController

// CoreData Related
@property (strong, nonatomic) DataModel *Model;

// Instance Methods
- (void)updateProfileData;

// Core Data Method
- (void)getProfile;

@end
```

This method is called in the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method. When I run this, I get the following error:

```
'+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Users''
```

I have found a similar question here on StackOverflow that may help, but I still don't understand what the solution actually is.

['+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter - Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596487/entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter-core-data)

The stated solution from that thread was that he passed the context to the ViewController. How is this accomplished? I already thought I was doing that.

EDIT: `DataModel.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "Workouts.h"
#import "sqlite3.h"

@interface DataModel : NSObject {
    sqlite3 *Database;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) Workouts *currentWorkout;

// Core Data Properties
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *storeCoordinator;

+ (DataModel *)sharedInstance;
- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

`DataModel.m`:

```
#import "DataModel.h"

@implementation DataModel

#pragma mark - Core Data

+ (DataModel *)sharedInstance {
   static DataModel *sharedModel = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       sharedModel = [[DataModel alloc] init];
       //sharedInstance.storeCoordinator = [sharedInstance storeCoordinator];
       //sharedInstance.managedObjectContext = [sharedInstance managedObjectContext];
   });
   return sharedModel;
}

- (void)saveContext {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([_managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", error.userInfo);
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data Stack

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self storeCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (_storeCoordinator != nil) {
        return _storeCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"model.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _storeCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:_managedObjectModel];
    if (![_storeCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    return _storeCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark Application's Documents Directory

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

@end
```

UPDATE: I realize the reason why the objects were `(null)`. I was trying to call the `sharedInstance` singleton method and they were not calling correctly. The getter was being called and would throw into a loop that would keep calling the getter. I correctly used the synthesized variables `_managedObjectContext` and `_storeCoordinator`. The objects now appropriately allocate memory and return the reference. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: What does your `NSLog` return?

Comment: Well, there's your answer. You don't have an instance of NSManagedObjectContext. How are you creating it in your DataModel class?

Comment: I added an update with the `managedObjectContext` method I used. This is a method I have used from tutorials.

Comment: Just post teh whole class somewhere, your managedObjectContext method looks fine, very probably your managedStoreCoordinator cannot open a data model for some reason.  Are you sure there are no warnings in the log file from the store coordinator?

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner I added the entire DataModel class.

Comment: So you are holding on to this class in the ApplicationDelegate?

Comment: I don't use ApplicationDelegate at all. I was going to implement this class as a Singleton before reading advice against singletons.

Comment: I may have taken the singleton use out of context. I would like to implement this class as a singleton that I can reference at any time.

Comment: Did you ever actually instantiate your DataModel class?

Comment: @sosborn I did. I updated the original DataModel code to include the singleton setup. I instantiate the object in the ViewController by calling `self.Model = [DataModel sharedInstance];`

Comment: You're creating a NSManagedObject with `alloc/init`, this is never going to work. Check out the Coredata docs for how to instantiate manage objects.

Comment: @Rog Where is this happening? The Core Data code is what I took from the Apple boiler plate. The `sharedModel = [[DataModel alloc] init];` line is not of type `NSManagedObject`. That is for my custom data model class.

Comment: You're right I just realised that. It's hard to read your code because you are breaking convention. Use lowercase for the first letter of your instances, use singular for model objects (i.e. `User` not `Users`). Besides that, have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with the Core Data Stack being created in the Application Delegate. Where have you read that this is the case.

It's certainly considered bad design to be calling down to the Application Delegate to get the managed object context, but what most people do is to pass a reference to the managed object context from the Application Delegate to the other view controllers that use it.

Comment: Take a look at MagicalRecord (git project).  This takes lots of headache out of using CoreData.

Comment: Or adds another layer between you and Core Data. It's a matter of opinion.

Comment: I myself almost always set up a CoreData helper singleton like this so that I don't have to import the application delegate everywhere.  That way I also keep CoreData imports out of the application delegate too...

Answer (score 1):

Dumb question:  Your model is in fact named DataModel?

Comment: This should be in the comments.

Comment: Not if it's the real answer to the original problem.  I asked question in the comments until we had enough data that the only real solution, however improbable. must be that he has the data model name wrong (or so I think).

Comment: Agreed.. Wrong datamodel name will also cause the same issue especially he has not added core data at the time of creating project and later on he added core data model with different name. And he copied all code of `Core Data Stack` from somewhere else where it was named DataModel. I did the same just today.