# CoreData and iCloud

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, icloud

I am developing a core data application and was thinking of adding iCloud support, but after looking around on the web I frequently heard that iCloud+CoreData is unreliable and will often break.

Is this true? A book I am reading on the subject of core data mentions that iCloud+CoreData was unreliable in iOS 5 but has since been fixed, however I have also heard the opposite, that iCloud+CoreData is still unreliable in iOS 6. If so would storing the database in a custom format help at all?

Comment: A lot of developers are still having trouble with Core Data iCloud sync even in iOS 6: see [this article](http://mentalfaculty.tumblr.com/post/51143164677/does-core-data-sync-quack) for a recent point of view.

Things may have improved in iOS 7: it's still under NDA so nobody's sharing their experiences yet.

Comment: @Amy What confuses me is that some people say it works and some say it won't, surely if there are structural problems with iCloud+CoreData their effects would be universal. By the way the linked article mentions the TICoreDataSync have you had any experience with this framework?

Comment: I have just posted a sample iOS library style Core Data app which includes iCloud integration. The app includes a Settings Bundle for the user to toggle "Use iCloud" preference settings and will migrate the store to and from iCloud depending on the users settings.

Download from the link below - sorry about the documentation - will get around to that at some point but it works much the same way as the UIManagedDocument example.

http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Now that iOS 7 has been released, we can talk about it. And everything would seem to indicate that in iOS 7 iCloud Core Data sync has been fixed. I'm about to add iCloud Core Data sync to an  (iOS 7 only) app I'm building, so I can't yet speak from personal experience, but everything I've heard suggests that it's now good for prime time.

I highly recommend watching the "What's New in Core Data and iCloud" session video from WWDC 2013: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=207 (requires an Apple Developer Program membership). I've watched it twice now, and they've certainly made things a **lot** more straightforward.

Lastly, I recommend taking a look at [UbiquityStoreManager](https://github.com/lhunath/UbiquityStoreManager) on GitHub. It's a library that pretty much does all the painful parts of iCloud Core Data for you. It's been modified to take into account the significant improvements in iOS 7, all though if you want to take advantage of them your app has to be iOS 7 only (that applies whether you use the library or not).

**UPDATE:** Since posting this answer, I now *can* speak from personal experience, and can confirm that Core Data iCloud Sync in iOS 7 is rock solid, and what's more, unbelievably easy to implement. I added it to my app without using [UbiquityStoreManager](https://github.com/lhunath/UbiquityStoreManager) or any other 3rd party library and it was very straightforward. Literally just a few lines of code.

**EDIT:** I created a GitHub repo with my iCloud Core Data stack for iOS 7. Hope it helps:
https://github.com/mluisbrown/iCloudCoreDataStack

Comment: Can you speak about the personal experience in this time?

Comment: @mluisbrown Up and running in no time. Thanks a lot! The gist was easy to implement, but why does it take so long for the external store to kick in after a reinstall? Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @AlexanderLongbeach no idea, but I think it's just the time it takes to access the iCloud servers. Nothing you can do about it AFAIK. I've noticed that on the simulator you pretty much have to force a sync manually (⇧⌘I) otherwise it will take for ever. No problems on a device.

Comment: Is it this simply integrated? There has to be more setup. Has to!

Comment: @foriinrangeawesome yep, it's really that simple :-)

Comment: @mluisbrown I just have one question. Do you know why I would be getting the error saying `entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name` in this case? I changed the methods for storeURL and modelURL, so I am not sure why this would be happening.

Comment: @foriinrangeawesome that error means your `NSManagedObjectContext` is nil. Either it never got initialised or you've set it to nil somewhere. See answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11596487/368085. Highly unlikely it's related to iCloud.

Comment: @mluisbrown I see what is wrong. My app now has to SQLite files, probably from a difference between your core data implementation and mine. Better look at that sooner than later.

Comment: @mluisbrown Do you know how to migrate existing non-iCloud stack to iCould?

Comment: @phantomlimb I do. Basically, you just use `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:` and provide the `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey` value in the options parameter. If you need more info, better contact me via e-mail rather than use these comments.

Comment: @mluisbrown Thank you! I'll try it out, and might bother you again with e-mail!

Comment: @mluisbrown Sometimes after I run migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error: I get my whole model duplicated. Looks like some of the times iCloud is automatically migrating it for me. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Abras `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:` will migrate all the data from one store to another. It does not do duplicate detection, that is up to you. So, if you migrate your local store to iCloud, and then back again, you'll end up with all your records duplicated. OTOH I *have* occasionally seen iCloud appear to automatically migrate data from a local store without calling `migrate...` at all. That's a bug.

Comment: @mluisbrown I think that Apple wanted it to be automatically. The bug is that it doesn't happen all the time. I know that I should detect and remove duplicates, but there is no way to know when iCloud automatically migrates it. So, there is no way to detect when the duplicates appear. My only option is to check on every new run, but this will still leave the user with duplicated entries for some time. Not to say that most of the times, after migrating, iCloud starts throwing a lot of different errors.

Comment: @Abras @mluisbrown While implementing this stack into my preexisting app, I had to leave out the `migrate...` because it happened automatically and it created duplicate entities. It is very convenient in that way, and have had no trouble with it (when I first implemented this stack, I wrote a lot of code to try to manually migrate, only to find that I did not have to. Would have been nicer to find out before the extraneous code was written!)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your PersistentStack! I've used it, but some users are reporting lost data after an app update - any ideas?

Comment: @hyouuu there's no reason an app update should cause data loss. However, if the app is deleted and re-installed, it may take some time (several minutes) for the app to sync its data with iCloud, and this may give the impression that data has disappeared. This is nothing to do with the PersistentStack, it's just iCloud being slow.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @mluisbrown! Unfortunately the user who reported lost didn't seem to have deleted the app; another observation is the sync is funky between an iPhone and iPad, one behavior is that items created from iPhone will appear on iPad, but not the other way around. Have you experienced similar issues at all?

Comment: @hyouuu I have had similar issues, all though given enough time all everything does sync up eventually. They are problems with iCloud itself, not the code. btw, if you want to continue this, please create an issue on GitHub, this isn't the right place for it :)

Comment: Thanks :) awesome! Keep updating this github repo . Love it

Comment: Finally, core data and iCloud are working together! Awesome work with GIT, best answer on entire web :-)

Comment: I got a Swift version based on @mluisbrown's iCloudCoreDataStack, with some Xcode generated code and Apple Technical support, at https://github.com/hyouuu/iCloudCoreData-Swift

I might have made obvious mistakes - please help make it better!

Comment: I just wonder how has everyone's experience been? My app users still randomly lose data after an app update or doing nothing from time to time :(

Comment: I realize I'm raising a very dead discussion here, but has anyone seen issues with this example github project now that ios9 / swift2 has been released? I am having unbelievable issues.

Comment: Things still aren’t that rosy as the answer suggests. We use the iCloud + Core Data stack since it was introduced and also went through all of Apple’s internal iterations to improve the stack. While it’s true that the current stack works way better than the old one, we still have unfixable issues that we discovered during beta tests in the last couple of weeks (it’s basically the worst case: lost user data).

Comment: hi @mluisbrown do you know if there is another way to write the public database as an administrator, to seed and maintain data, without requiring an icloud login? full question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808601/seed-and-maintain-cloudkit-public-database-still-requires-icloud-login

Answer (score 10):

It seems that the video/link (https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=207) mentioned by @mluisbrown is no longer available.

There is a newer version as of 2021:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10015/

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the link in the answer and up voted your answer to help you along to 50+ rep :)

Answer (score 2):

In macOS 10.15 and iOS 13 Apple has introduced [NSPersistentCloudKitContainer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcloudkitcontainer) which is

> A container that encapsulates the Core Data stack in your app and mirrors select persistent stores to a CloudKit private database.

Links:

[Apple Documentation: Mirroring a Core Data Store with CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit)

[Apple Sample Code: Synchronizing a Local Store to the Cloud](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/synchronizing_a_local_store_to_the_cloud)