# Integrating iCloud into a Core Data app on iOS 7. How can I go about doing this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud

After quite a bit of searching Google, I'm surprised that I can't find something to walk me through this process. The Apple docs have a 'Design Guide', but no sample app or tutorial.

At the moment I'm a bit in the dark. What I'd like are the steps I'll need to take to do this from scratch - OR a link to a tutorial if one exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CoreData and iCloud](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065237/coredata-and-icloud)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too had this problem. After searching for months for a tutorial or sample code- `<sarcasm>`thanks for the help Apple!`</sarcasm>` - I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059284/2035473). The developer created a GitHub class that makes this much *much* easier.

This guy hit the nail straight on with this implementation.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer especially as you are not adding anything to the answer you have linked to.