# The Right Way to do Core Data and iCloud with iOS 7 Only Apps

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, icloud

I have a simple `Core-Data` based application which is a `UITableView` populated by the user filling in some `UITextFields`, with the UITableView getting updated via `NSFetchedResultsController`.

As an iOS 7 only app and right now in the App Store without `iCloud` enabled, it's working really well. However, the time has come to introduce iCloud.

I have spent a long time reading iOS 7 specifics with iCloud and Core Data, including the WWDC videos from 2013 relating to this very topic. I've also read the excellent http://www.objc.io/issue-10/icloud-core-data.html page with reference to the easier methods. I've read this excellent post [CoreData and iCloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065237/coredata-and-icloud) and followed the Git code, but I'm confused.

**Problem**

My issue right now is not a problem; it's where to begin. Unfortunately, as good as all of the posts are, they don't tailor to newbies in this field.

I have a few questions that are preventing me from even starting with entire reference to: http://www.objc.io/issue-10/icloud-core-data.html .

1) The code that he has pasted in there with the notifications and the iCloud Support pragma marks, do I put that both in the App Delegate?

2) Where the comment states, use these options in your call to -`addPersistentStore`. What do I do with that? I can see that that is called from the persistentStoreCoorindator, but what exact options do I put in there for simple synching?

3) Where does the `iCloudPersistentStoreOptions` method get called from?

4) Do I have to change anything in the `ManagedObjectContext` method or the `PersistentStoreCoordinator` method?

5) Do I have to have a notification `UITableView` that refreshes the UI?

I've read so many posts on iOS 5 and iOS 6 articles and what I want is:

App with data updates to the new version with iCloud enabled, uploads information to the iCloud and other devices with the same iCloud account, downloading that data.

**Update**

I have spent some time figuring this out yesterday and I think I'm almost there. After watching the WWDC videos again, I've figured out the answers to question 1, 2 and 3 earlier, but I have an issue whereby the App Store version of my app (without iCloud) has some data and when I upload to the new development build with iCloud, all of my data is not appearing in the UI (though it does exist in Core Data because I'm seeing a core data backup in the settings on the device).

I achieved this with the following persistentStoreCoordinator code:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Planner.sqlite"];
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *url = [fm URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                              NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                              NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : @"Planner"
                              };


    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

I'm stuck on question 4 and 5 above though. Do I have to change anything else in the persistentStoreCoordinator and do I have to change anything in the NSManagedObjectContext? Finally, question 5 - do I have to change a notification in the actual TableView, because the data isn't displaying and I suspect that it's currently just not updating it's UI..

Any guidance on this question would be really appreciated.

Comment: You might find this sample app useful http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to set a `mergePolicy` on the context.
2. You need to make sure you have implemented the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods for inserting/deleting/moving rows.
3. You need to call the `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` method on the queue of your context (e.g. main queue if your using a main thread context) when you receive the `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` notification.

Comment: Thanks so much @Drew for the response. I'm happy to say that in your answers, I have number 2 done for sure (the app works perfectly before the attempted iCloud synching, including deleting with the NSFRC) and following http://www.objc.io/issue-10/icloud-core-data.html I now have number 3 done as well. That's all good. However I'm not quite sure where I would do number 1. Would the mergePolicy be done in the managedObjectContext, or as part of a specific notification?

Comment: Just set a merge policy when you init your context. It's just a property of the MOC.

Comment: Many thanks Drew - that did it and it now works like a charm! I have a few other issues but I'm going to try work through those. Thanks again for your assistance with this!