# Core Data entity error with xmpp

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uiviewcontroller

I am using XMPP Framework's Core Data message storage and I want to add to my app another Core Data Entity, I create .xcdatamodeld and create Entity, I add code to my `AppDelegate`, but I get error. Can it be because I use XMPP Framework's Core Data message storage and how to fix it?

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext_messageList];
NSManagedObject *contexNew = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserProfileEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[contexNew setValue:@1 forKey:@"id"];
[contexNew setValue:@"name TEST" forKey:@"name"];
[contexNew setValue:@"test YEP" forKey:@"test"];
NSError *error;
if ([context save:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
}
```

It crashes on on second line with

> '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter
>   searching for entity name 'UserProfileEntity''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that `nil` is not a legal thing to pass for the managed object context. So, did you inject the context in the correct manner? I mean that the following line

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext_messageList];
```

should have a counterpart like

```
yourController.managedObjectContext_messageList = theContextYouWantToInject;
```

or

```
[yourController setManagedObjectContext_messageList:theContextYouWantToInject];
```

If you are using segues here a useful discussion: ['+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter - Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596487/entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter-core-data).

In addition, are you sure you are providing a valid store coordinator? For further references take a look to [The Core Data Stack](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/09/07/the-core-data-stack/).