# +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'IndianGroceries'

Tags: ios

I am getting an error when I am trying to load my data from Core Data to a Table View controller. I had corrected the code as per the discussions in forum but still i'm getting an error.

**SearchViewController**

```
@interface SearchViewController ()

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@implementation SearchViewController
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize searchBar,tView;
@synthesize noResultsLabel;

 -(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

 -(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.tView.delegate = self;
    self.tView.dataSource = self;

    noResultsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 90, 200, 30)];
    [self.view addSubview:noResultsLabel];
    noResultsLabel.text = @"No Results";
    [noResultsLabel setHidden:YES];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

 -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];

}

#pragma mark - Search bar delegate

 -(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
{

    NSError *error;

    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) 
{

        NSLog(@"Error in search %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    } else 
{

        [self.tView reloadData];
        [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

        [noResultsLabel setHidden:_fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count > 0];

    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

 -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id  sectionInfo =
    [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

}

 -(void)configureCell:(TableCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    IndianGroceries *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.lblCountry.text = info.country;
    cell.lblCityName.text = info.cityName;
    cell.lblEmailId.text = info.emailId;
    cell.lblFirstName.text = info.firstName;
    cell.lblLastName.text = info.lastName;
    cell.lblPhoneNumber.text = info.phoneNumber;
    cell.lblStreetName.text = info.streetName1;
    cell.lblStreetName2.text = info.streetName2;
    cell.lblZipCode.text = info.zipCode;
}

  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[self.tView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell=[[TableCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - fetchedResultsController

// Change this value to experiment with different predicates
#define SEARCH_TYPE 0


 -(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"IndianGroceries" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"country" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSArray *queryArray;

    if ([self.searchBar.text rangeOfString:@":"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        queryArray = [self.searchBar.text componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    }

    NSLog(@"search is %@", self.searchBar.text);

    NSPredicate *pred;

    switch (SEARCH_TYPE) {

        case 0: // name contains, case sensitive
            pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS %@", self.searchBar.text];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:nil]; // better to not use cache
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

**DataViewController**

```
@interface DataViewController ()
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray *SearchResultContries;
//- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end

@implementation DataViewController
@synthesize contacts;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;

-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)])
    {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(showSearch)];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    //here we get the car from the president data store (or) the database
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"IndianGroceries"];
    contacts = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void) showSearch {

    SearchViewController *searchViewController = [[SearchViewController alloc] init];
    searchViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    searchViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchView"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:searchViewController animated:YES];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return contacts.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellID";
    TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
      cell=[[TableCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSManagedObject *con = [contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.lblEmailId setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[con valueForKey:@"emailId"]]];
    [cell.lblFirstName setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[con valueForKey:@"firstName"]]];
    [cell.lblLastName setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[con valueForKey:@"lastName"]]];
    [cell.lblStreetName setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[con valueForKey:@"streetName1"]]];
    [cell.lblStreetName2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[con valueForKey:@"streetName2"]]];
    [cell.lblCityName setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[con valueForKey:@"cityName"]]];
    [cell.lblZipCode setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[con valueForKey:@"zipCode"]]];
    [cell.lblPhoneNumber setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[con valueForKey:@"phoneNumber"]]];
    [cell.lblCountry setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[con valueForKey:@"country"]]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: Which line is the error happening on? Have you added an exception breakpoint? You will then be able to see what is nil and why.

Comment: Yeah the error is in the last line of the below code : -(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"IndianGroceries" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

Answer (score -1):

The `NSManagedObjectContext` you are passing to `entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` is nil. That method requires a valid NSManagedObjectContext instance.

See this answer:
['+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter - Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596487/entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter-core-data?rq=1)

Comment: This isn't an answer. If a question is a duplicate then vote to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: It is an answer. His question is "why am i getting this error". It is because his context is nil. He did not provide enough information in his question to show him exactly how to resolve it, and not enough information to determine wether it is a duplicate. Either way, his issue is that he's passing in a nil context.

Comment: And your answer is "look at the answer to this other Stack Overflow question".

Comment: I don wanna know "why am getting this error" i just wanna solve this error. Help me with solution.

Comment: No. My answer is "that method requires a valid NSManagedObjectContext instance". I pointed him to another question because he provided no information that indicated why his context was nil, and that may push him in the correct direction.