# '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data

I'm trying add data to CoreData.
This is my code.But I'm getting this error.What should I do in this case ?

That is my ViewController.h

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

And This is my .m file

```
       Person *person = [[Person alloc] initWithJSONString:string];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObjectContext *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Users" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [object setValue:person.name forKey:@"name"];
    [object setValue:person.id forKey:@"userId"];
    [object setValue:person.statu forKey:@"statu"];
    [object setValue:person.token forKey:@"token"];
    [object setValue:person.sonuc forKey:@"sonuc"];

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) return managedObjectContext;

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {

        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return managedObjectContext;
}
```

This is error.

```
'+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Users''
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your entity name is likely to be `User` (singular), not `Users`.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596487/entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter-core-data?rq=1

Comment: not changed anything.I'm getting same error.

Comment: What does `+ entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` deliver? It is `nil`, too. (I expect that, just for checking.) Is `managedObjectContext` non-nil?

Comment: does `[self persistentStoreCoordinator]` return `nil`?

Comment: yes its returning nil

Comment: Actually context is returning nil too how can i fix it

Answer (score 1):

The heart of your problem is that you have not thought about where `persistentStoreCoordinator` comes from, and this object is never created.

Your check, `if (coordinator != nil)`, is hiding this problem. Instead, you should aim to set things up so `coordinator` is never `nil`. Then the check can be removed or, even better, replaced with an assertion that this is the case: `NSAssert(coordinator != nil, @"There is no persistent store coordinator.")`.

If the persistent store coordinator comes from outside this view controller, I recommend passing it as part of the view controller’s initialisation. If the view controller can set up the persistent store coordinator itself, either do this as part of its initialisation or load it lazily.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use

```
NSManagedObjectContext *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([YourClass class]) inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

You don't need to use hardcoded string as it may have typing errors.

In your case it must be

```
NSManagedObjectContext *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Users class]) inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's saying
Use of undeclared identifier 'User' now

Comment: what is the name of your class?

Comment: The relationship between entity (types) and classes is to-many. There can be many entities using the same class, in fact this is the default!